# В админке WordPress делаются ненужные запросы

Tags: wordpress, запрос, профилирование

Админ панель моего сайта медленно работает. С помощью плагина Query Monitor я выяснил, что плагины выполняют запросы в админке практически на каждой странице, хотя по факту они должны быть задействованы для просмотра редактирования post_type.

Например, в Dashboard (и в других страницах) плагин со-авторов зачем-то выполняет select запросы, хотя в действительности он должен их выполнять только на странице с записями.

Каким способом мне это исправить?

Comment: Поставить другой плагин/написать свой

Comment: Можно использовать плагин Plugin Organizer

Comment: Еще можно написать авторам таких плагинов.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Отключением ненужных плагинов и заменой их функционала кастомным кодом 
2 - Рефакторингом используемого плагина (решение для отчаяных)
3 - Можете попробовать использовать аналоги плагинов, возможно есть написанные лучше.

В целом разработчики плагинов не особо заморачиваюстя над качеством кода, отсюда такие проблемы. Очевидного и прочтого решения  к сожалению нету.